# Manage number of address lines

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, address

Where ,i can change the number of address lines on the checkout page? Next code returns the number but where to set it?

```
$this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines();
```

Comment: did you even try a search on Magento SE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The address is not just on checkout page, but in profile too. Anyway, in admin panel go to `System → Configuration → Customers → Customer Configuration` open `Name and Adress options` and the is `Number of Lines in a Street Address`. Here you can set it.

Comment: Works for magento ce 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 3):

This applies to Magento Enterprise Edition 1.13 and up.

To Manage your Street Lines for Customer Addresses. You need to log into Magento Admin Panel. Go to Customers Menu -> Attributes -> Manage Customer Address Attributes.

Select Street.

Enter the number of lines you want for your address on the first page. It can be up to 20 lines.

Please remember to change your store scope on the left if you want different addresses for different store views / websites / scope.

Click Save.

Done!

Comment: Hmmm...there is no such menu in the default CE-1.7 version. or any other community version. Are you sure you don't have an extension? Or maybe you are using EE?

Comment: I am running EE 1.13.0.1, this is not available in the CE Versions.

Comment: Well...the questionw as tagged [tag:ce-1.7.0.2]. So your answer does not apply.

Comment: Ahhh! Didn't see the tag!

Answer (score 1):

Go in magento admin -> configuration-> Customer -> Customer Configuration-> Name and Address Options (TAB) ->Number of Lines in a Street Address and type number of streets must be 1-4